# How to handle CodePipeline SourceArtifact in AWS Lambda with Java handler?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-codepipeline

I am trying to build a Docker image that I will use in AWS Lambda which will be invoked from AWS CodePipeline..

I have already tried a bunch of various DTO structures, but so far with no luck. My most recent try is as follows:

```
public class LambdaHandler
    implements RequestHandler<Map<String, String>, String> {

  private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LambdaHandler.class);

  @Override
  public String handleRequest(Map<String, String> event, Context context) {
```

But in cloudwatch I see:

```
Caused by: java.io.UncheckedIOException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token
```

My pipeline in AWS Codepipeline has 2 stages.. First one checks out code from AWS and second one is the Lambda call.

Stage 1 has Action Provider Github (Version 2). Output artifact format is *CodePipeline default* Output artifacts is *SourceArtifact*

Stage 2 (where I call the lambda function in the docker image) has Action Provider AWS Lambda. Input artifacts is *SourceArtifact* .

My goal is to do some processing on the files checked out in Stage 1. But I am unable to figure out how to connect the output of Stage 1 and feed it as an input to Stage 2. I *think* I need the `s3BucketName` and the `s3LocationKey` so that I can download the checked out code, but no matter what I tried, does not seem to be working.

What is the structure of the DTO I should implement in the `RequestHandler`s first parameter? In other words what should be `Map<String, String> event` so that I see some data in it?